# NS_ENUM object not compile after added in bridging header file

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

I have one enum which is in constant.h file ( Objective-C )

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, EEFieldType) {
  EEFieldTypeHighFields = 1,
  EEFieldTypeMediumFields = 2,
  EEFieldTypeLowFields = 3
};
```

I have one bridging file which is connect to swift code and importing one file which file name is profile.

(ModuleName-Bridging-Header.h)

```
#import "Profile.h"
```

profile file using below method which is not compiled in code.

```
- (EEFieldType)fieldTypeByPFType;
```

Error : Expected a type on EEFieldType.

Comment: Can you please reframe your question, its quite confusing to answer. I am not getting what exactly what is the question

Comment: @SurbhiGarg reframe question might be you will get idea what i am trying to convey.

Comment: `Profile.h` references `EEFieldType`, which is defined in `constant.h`, does `Profile.h` import `constant.h`? If not, why not? If yes you need to provide more information for people to be able to help you.

Comment: @CRD Yes , Actually "constant.h" i had added in pch file which is globally defined.

Comment: So if I follow you correctly `Profile.h` is not importing `constant.h` but instead you are relying on the pre-complied header (`pch`) facility of Xcode for *Objective-C*. There is no Swift equivalent of the `pch` file, and use of `pch` file with Objective-C has been discouraged in favour of modules for some time. Have you tried importing `constant.h` directly in `Profile.h`?

Comment: @CRD Not, I tried after you told me.. and it's works perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Answer moved and expanded from comments]*

With the additional information on the use of a pre-compiled header file (`.pch`) added in the comments, your problem comes down to Swift not using `.pch` files – they are an Objective-C compiler feature.

In Objective.c `Profile.h` compiles as the header it depends on, `constant.h`, is imported by the `.pch`.

In Swift `Profile.h` produces the missing type error as it does not import `constant.h` which defines the type.

Simply import `constant.h` in `Profile.h`.

Note: Doing this not only works for Swift it continues to work correctly for Objective-C – the `.pch` feature is a compiler option to speed up header processing and the Objective-C compiler will continue to use it, when it sees the `constant.h` import in `Profile.h` it will simple skip it as already imported by the `.pch`.